# Controllers glide over eatchother

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem with my controllers that glide over eatchother when i change the with of my grid. Here is the code of my layout. I don't know why this happend. Could anyone help me with a solution and explane for me why this problem apear? Logically you would think that the controllers can't move in a way that they overlay eatchother.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Labb_2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Labb_2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Din lottorad:" Width="150" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal1" TextChanged="inputTal1_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal2" TextChanged="inputTal2_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal3" TextChanged="inputTal3_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal4" TextChanged="inputTal4_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal5" TextChanged="inputTal5_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal6" TextChanged="inputTal6_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="inputTal7" TextChanged="inputTal7_TextChanged"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Margin="5"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Foreground="Red" Name="errorText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="110,0,0,5" FontSize="22" Text="Antal dragningar:" Width="200"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox MinWidth="300" Width="350" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="AmountOfRounds" VerticalAlignment="center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
            <Button Background="LightBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="60,0,0,5" Click="Button_Click">
                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock>StartaLotto</TextBlock>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Button.ContentTemplate>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="3" Text="5 rätt:" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,25,5"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="140" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="FiveCorrect" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="30,0,0,5"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="4" Text="6 rätt:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="SixCorrect" Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="6" Text="7 rätt:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="140" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="SevenCorrect" Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,27,5"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: What you got is expected. You need to adjust your XAML code to make it adaptive.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with my controllers that glide over eatchother when i change the with of my grid.

This is expected behavior. You are using [Proportional sizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#layout-properties)(also called star sizing) in your `Grid`. Proportional sizing distributes available space among the rows and columns of a grid by weighted proportions.

When you change the width of the `Grid`, the available space among the columns will change as well. For example, if you resize the width of the third `Gird` from 1000 to 500, then each column will also change from 100 to 50 thus controls will overlayed.

It's recommended to use [adaptive layouts with state triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#set-visual-states-in-xaml-markup). You could use [AdaptiveTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger?view=winrt-22621) to check the states and change your layout based on the width of the Grid.